# replace "&amp;" to "&" in xml in mule 4

Tags: mule, mulesoft, mule4

I have a XML where I want to replace `&amp;` with `&`. I tried to convert the XML to JSON and replace `&amp;` with `&`. Also tried to make it as a string but at last when I'm transforming it into XML again getting the `&amp;`.
How can I fix this?

Input:

```
<data>&amp;lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?&amp;gt;&amp;lt;bridge &amp;gt;</data>
```

Expectation:

```
<data>&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?&gt;&lt;bridge &;gt;</data>
```

Comment: .....and what **exactly** have you tried?

Comment: Also, you should add the expected output for your JSON output which is what the real final output should be.
I don't understand `replace "&" to "&"`. Aren't both the same? I think you are referring to the XML escaped representations. Please confirm.

Comment: @aled yes aled. i have to replace "&amp;" to "&" in the xml. There is no any json. input is xml and output is xml only diffrence is in the output "&amp;" should replace with "&"

Comment: @NicoHaase I've to replace "&amp" with "&" in the xml. I tried to make my payload as string and replace "&amp" with "&". at the last when I'm transforming my payload to xml it's automatically considering "&amp". amp tag i don't want as per my requirement. only "&" is required. please help here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible @Devendra. If you have to format your data in XML and your data contains '&' then it **MUST** be escaped with an extra 'amp;'.

I too faced a similar issue in one of my requirements and after searching a lot around the internet, there was no work-around for this.

Let me know if you've find out any way.

Answer (score 0):

@Devendra Please try to unescape the XML data first and then automatically it converts to escape XML data.

```html
Eg: input: <data><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><bridge ></data> result: <data>&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?&gt;&lt;bridge &gt;</data>
```

Thanks,
Nag

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to add all of the relevant information, correctly formatted. Don't add to your answer in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst i appreciate that this quite an old question, i recently came across it whilst trying to solve my own problem.

It was a multi-stage solution, i can't share the full dataweave's but i'll run through the steps i needed to do to solve this.

**Stage One** - build the XML into the correct format from the JSON payload
I used

```
%dw 2.0
output application/xml inlineCloseOn="empty",writeDeclaration=false
---
{
authResponse: {
    messageInformation...
plus some payload manipulation.
```

**Stage Two** - output the XML as a string
I used

```
%dw 2.0
output text/plain
---
write(payload, 'application/xml', {"writeDeclaration":false})
```

**Stage Three** - simple string replace

```
%dw 2.0
output text/plain
---
read(payload 
        replace '>' with '&gt;'
        replace '<' with '&lt;', 'text/plain')
```

**Stage Four** - final stage, use a "Set Payload" component, not a dataweave.  Set the envelope/header/body tags etc as static text with a ++ for payload in the middle.  I forgot to close the tags initially, so do forget that.
The most important bit about this is **"MIME Type" which was set to "text/xml" not "application/xml"**.  This prevented the conversion back to `"&amp;lt;"`

```
<set-payload value='#["&lt;soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"&gt;&#10;    &lt;soap:Body&gt;&#10;        &lt;ns1:authRequestResponse xmlns:ns1=\"http://SGBD.org/\"&gt;&#10;            &lt;authRequestResult xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xs=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xsi:type=\"xs:string\"&gt;"&#10;++&#10;       payload&#10;++&#10;"&lt;/authRequestResult&gt;&#10;        &lt;/ns1:authRequestResponse&gt;&#10;    &lt;/soap:Body&gt;&#10;&lt;/soap:Envelope&gt;"]' doc:name="wrap soap headers around string" doc:id="409ec01d-6c7b-49f4-8eab-868ea2d09921" mimeType="text/xml"/>
```

I'm sure i can tidy up the code to be more efficient, pretty sure stage two and stage three can be done in one step.  I'm also quite happy that the headers and namespace are static in the responses so i don't have to worry about them.

The resulting payload was:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
    <ns1:authRequestResponse xmlns:ns1="http://SGBD.org/">
        <authRequestResult xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">&lt;authResponse&gt;
&lt;messageInformation&gt;
&lt;requestingServer&gt;blah&lt;/requestingServer&gt;
....
&lt;/messageInformation&gt;
&lt;/authResponse&gt;</authRequestResult>
    </ns1:authRequestResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

This might not work for you but the "Set-Payload using plain/xml" instead of a dataweave saved us.